# combining groups in sql containing substrings

Tags: sql-server

I apologize in advance for not explaining this very well.
I have a sql database with some data like this:

```
column1 | groups     
3323052 | 3323052,3324794,3324795   
3324794 | 3323052,3324794   
3324794 | 3324794   
3324794 | 3324794,3763369   
3353586 | 3353586   
3763369 | 3324794,3763369
```

I want to combine groups so that if a number is in two groups, the groups will combine and the number will only show up once in the list.

For example, the final result would look like this:

> groups
>
> 3323052,3324794,3324795,3763369
>
> 3353586

I have been googling around without much luck.  Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What needs to happen to the value in column1 after the groups are combined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to recursively replace any items in groups -column with any values found from other rows with that value in column1? At least you can do it this way:

1. Split the data into rows, so there's just column1 -> group relation
2. Fetch any values that can be used as root nodes, my approach takes the smallest value because your data has a circle (3323052 -> 3324794 -> 3323052)
3. Fetch recursively all the value that can be found from the hierarchy under these root nodes
4. Put it back together into the original format

This example uses [DelimitedSplit8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) by Jeff Moden:

```
-- Step 1:
select distinct
  d.column1,
  convert(int, s.Item) as item
into #tmp
from
  data d
  cross apply DelimitedSplit8k(d.groups, ',') s

-- Step 2:
select distinct 
  column1
into #root
from #tmp t1
where not exists 
(select 1 from #tmp t2 where t2.item = t1.column1 and t2.item > t2.column1)

-- Step 3:
;with CTE (root, parent, child) as (
  select r.column1, r.column1, r.column1 from #root r
  union all
  select C.root, t.column1, t.item
  from CTE C join #tmp t on t.column1 = C.child and t.item > C.parent
)  
select distinct * into #results from CTE

-- Step 4:
SELECT r.column1, STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + convert(varchar(50), r2.child)
    FROM #results r2
    WHERE r2.root = r.column1
    ORDER BY ', ' + convert(varchar(50), r2.child)
    FOR XML PATH(N'')), 1, 2, '') as groups
FROM #root r
GROUP BY column1
ORDER BY column1
```

Result:

```
column1     groups
3323052     3323052, 3324794, 3324795, 3763369
3353586     3353586
```

I used temp. tables to be sure each of the steps is executed just once, but I believe it would be possible to do the whole thing with just one select and using CTEs instead of temp tables.

You can test this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d24f6/33)